# Java - can't seem to addActionListener to a class that contains JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

So I have this class:

```
class Button extends JButton
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Button(int x,int y, int size, JLayeredPane pane )
    {

        JButton b = new JButton();
        pane.add(b, new Integer(0));
        b.setBounds(x,y,size,size);

    }
}
```

This, although doesn't do much all works. but i want it to addActionListener to the jbutton in the class. But I don't seem to be able to get this to work. If i try adding it outside the class it doesnt give an error but doesn't seem to do anything either. Ive tried all sorts of stuff like passing in the JFrame...

For a bit more context, this is for a Minesweeper game. also the Jframe uses a LayeredPane

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: How do you invoke `addActionListener()`?

Comment: Agree that your question is very unclear. Please let us know more about how exactly it is not working. One thing I can tell you is that this class should not extend JButton.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need to extend JButton in this case.  Unless you are overriding some of the methods to change the behavior, just use a JButton

Comment: I would surmise that you are attaching the `ActionListener` to the instance of `Button` and not the instance that you created in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor:

```
public Button(int x,int y, int size, JLayeredPane pane )
{
  //The whole premise of have a constructor that declares a JButton inside
  //a JButton doesn't really make any sense, but:
  super();

  JButton b = new JButton();
  pane.add(b, new Integer(0));
  b.setBounds(x,y,size,size);

  b.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){ 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      System.out.println("Button Clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

This is just declaring a new JButton in your Buttons constructor.

Having said that it looks like you don't understand how the code you've written works.  When you extend JButton you're getting all its methods through inheritance.  `public Button()` is your `Button` class's constructor, you don't need to declare a JButton inside of it, Button is already a JButton.  What you need to do is, in another class, do something like `Button b = new Button();` and then declare your actionlistener on button.

Check out these resources for more information:

[JButton api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

[How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Note Grammin is not extending JButton!

Comment: Note Grammin is providing a constructor.  Constructors don't extend anything.  That said, his constructor should probably call `super`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, i tried quite a few things, and was left quite confused then started extending classes unnecessarily. the line b.addActionlistener(new ActionListener ... is exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot. Usually when adding buttons i go: addActionListener(this) because it's in a JFrame subclass... never know how to do it otherwise

Comment: Remember...implicit call to `super()`.

Comment: @user2718803 its import to understand why "this" didn't work in this situation.  You should read this document also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

There are more way to do that.

I suggest you to see http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~bert/courses/1007/slides/Lecture6.pdf at page 4 and page 5-6
That's are two example that Can explain you how to do